# Как "вынуть" из базы данных нужную ячейку?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Доброе утро! У меня есть боковое меню и один фрагмент. Мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию на каждую кнопку бокового меню менялся текст в этом фрагменте. База данных создана, а вот как забрать я не пойму. Насколько я понял нужно это прописать в `switch` в  `private void displayView`. Вот мой код.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView myDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle myDrawerToggle;

    // navigation drawer title
    private CharSequence myDrawerTitle;
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence myTitle;

    private String [] viewsNames;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Инициализируем наш класс-обёртку
        DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        // База нам нужна для записи и чтения
        SQLiteDatabase sqdb = dbh.getWritableDatabase();

        // закрываем соединения с базой данных
        sqdb.close();
        dbh.close();

        myTitle = getTitle();
        myDrawerTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.menu);

        ListView  

        viewsNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.views_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        myDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);      

        myDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, viewsNames));

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        myDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.open_menu,
                R.string.close_menu
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(myTitle);
                // название в ActionBar при закрытом меню
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(myDrawerTitle);
                // название в ActionBar при открытом меню
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(myDrawerToggle);        

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

        myDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(
                AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id
        ) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }    

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FirstFragment();                
                break;

            case 1:
                fragment = new FirstFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new FirstFragment();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            myDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            myDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(viewsNames[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(myDrawerList);

        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (myDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if navigation drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(myDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        myTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(myTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        myDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        myDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final Context fContext;
    // имя базы данных
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "colorcat_database.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "cattable";

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        // версия базы данных последняя цифра
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        fContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + "title TEXT, " + ");");

        // Добавляем записи в таблицу
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        // Получим файл из ресурсов
        Resources res = fContext.getResources();

        // Открываем xml-файл
        XmlResourceParser _xml = res.getXml(R.xml.cats_records);
        try {
            // Ищем конец документа
            int eventType = _xml.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                // Ищем теги record
                if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                        && (_xml.getName().equals("record"))) {
                    // Тег Record найден, теперь получим его атрибуты и
                    // вставляем в таблицу
                    String title = _xml.getAttributeValue(0);
                    values.put("title", title);
                    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                }
                eventType = _xml.next();
            }
        }
        // Catch errors
        catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            Log.e("Test", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Test", e.getMessage(), e);

        } finally {
            // Close the xml file
            _xml.close();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Запишем в журнал
        Log.w("TestBase", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        // Удаляем старую таблицу и создаём новую
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        // Создаём новую таблицу
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Буду благодарен, если подскажете что использовать и где. Спасибо!

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B+SQL

Comment: похоже что ошибок у вас много, без просмотра layout-ов не обойтись. Из приведенного кода возникает вопрос зачем вы сразу после отрытия подключения к БД, сразу же ее закрываете? как же вы с ней дальше работать то будете?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример считывания данных с БД. После `SQLiteDatabase sqdb = dbh.getWritableDatabase();` нужно открыть `cursor` к БД, затем переместится на нужную строку:
moveToFirst() — перемещает курсор на первую строку в результате запроса;
moveToNext() — перемещает курсор на следующую строку;
moveToLast() - перемещает курсор на последнюю строку;
moveToPrevious() — перемещает курсор на предыдущую строку;
getCount() — возвращает количество строк в результирующем наборе данных;
getColumnIndexOrThrow() — возвращает индекс для столбца с указанным именем   (выбрасывает исключение, если столбец с таким именем не существует);
getColumnName() — возвращает имя столбца с указанным индексом;
getColumnNames() — возвращает массив строк, содержащий имена всех столбцов в объекте Cursor;
moveToPosition() — перемещает курсор на указанную строку;
getPosition() — возвращает текущую позицию курсора

присваиваем переменные столбцам таблицы(строки на которую установили курсор)
закрываем курсор  `cursor.close()`
ну а дальше записываем значение нужной ячейки в `EditText`

```
mDatabaseHelper3 = new DBHelper(this, "mydb.db", null, 1);
        mSqLiteDatabase3 = mDatabaseHelper3.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor;
        cursor = mSqLiteDatabase3.query("tarif", new String[] {DBHelper.VODA_GOR_TARIF_COLUMN, DBHelper.VODA_HOL_TARIF_COLUMN, DBHelper.SVET_DEN_TARIF_COLUMN, DBHelper.SVET_NOCH_TARIF_COLUMN, DBHelper.VODOOTVOD_TARIF_COLUMN},
                null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToPosition(0);

        double tarif_vh = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.VODA_HOL_TARIF_COLUMN));
        double tarif_vg = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.VODA_GOR_TARIF_COLUMN));
        double tarif_sd = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.SVET_DEN_TARIF_COLUMN));
        double tarif_sn = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.SVET_NOCH_TARIF_COLUMN));
        double tarif_vo = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.VODOOTVOD_TARIF_COLUMN));
        cursor.close();
        EditText currentTarifGor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.currentTarifGor);
        EditText currentTarifHol = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.currentTarifHol);
        EditText currentTarifVodootvod = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.currentTarifVodootvod);
        EditText currentTarifDen = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.currentTarifDen);
        EditText currentTarifNoch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.currentTarifNoch);
        currentTarifDen.setText(""+tarif_sd);
        currentTarifGor.setText(""+tarif_vg);
        currentTarifHol.setText(""+tarif_vh);
        currentTarifNoch.setText(""+tarif_sn);
        currentTarifVodootvod.setText(""+tarif_vo);
```

Почитай этот урок, если я правильно тебя понял, то это то что тебе нужно.
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/cursor.php

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.